# print a paragraph that contains more than 2 patterns using awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

I want to print only the paragraphs that begin with "select" and end with ";", but should contain "IN cccc" for example if I have the following code

```
select aaaa
bbbb
IN cccc
;
select dddd
eeeee
IN ffff
;
select rrrr
eeeee
IN cccc
;
```

the result would be like

```
select aaaa
bbbb
IN cccc
;
select rrrr
eeeee
IN cccc
;
```

so here's the awk I used `awk '/^select*/,/^;/{if ($0 ~ /^IN cccc/) ; print}' inputfile` 
but I get as a result the entire content of my file

Comment: @fedorqui  I used the following awk but it seems that I am missing something "awk '/^select*/,/^;/{if ($0 ~ /^IN cccc/) ; print}' inputfile

Comment: Your problem is the wrong placement of a semicolon. You mean `if ($0 ~ /^IN cccc/) { print };` Of course, fixing that problem is not enough to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS=";"} /^[[:space:]]*select.*IN cccc/' file
```

Here,

- `ORS` - Output Record Separator
- `RS`  - Input Record Separator

Comment: Note: `\s` is specific to GNU awk. Use `[[:space:]]` if you use nawk or mawk.

Comment: That will falsely print a record that contains `selection RUIN cccc`. idk if that can happen or if it's OK if it does - if it's a problem add word boundaries (GNU awk) or spaces or newlines or something around the words you care about....